# better slick dynamic query coding style

Tags: scala, slick

```
private def buildQuery(query: TweetQuery) = {
      var q = Tweets.map { t =>
        t
      }
      query.isLocked.foreach { isLocked =>
        q = q.filter(_.isLocked === isLocked)
      }
      query.isProcessed.foreach { isProcessed =>
        q = q.filter(_.processFinished === isProcessed)
      }
      query.maxScheduleAt.foreach { maxScheduleAt =>
        q = q.filter(_.expectScheduleAt < maxScheduleAt)
      }
      query.minScheduleAt.foreach { minScheduleAt =>
        q = q.filter(_.expectScheduleAt > minScheduleAt)
      }
      query.status.foreach { status =>
        q = q.filter(_.status === status)
      }
      query.scheduleType.foreach { scheduleType =>
        q = q.filter(_.scheduleType === scheduleType)
      }
      q
    }
```

I am writing things like above to do dynamic query. really boring, any way better to do this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe the MaybeFilter can help you https://gist.github.com/cvogt/9193220

Answer (score 2):

I modified the answer of **[cvogt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/467390/cvogt)** in order to work with **slick 2.1.0**. Explanations of what have changed are in [here](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0/upgrade.html).

Hope it helps someone :)

```
  case class MaybeFilter[X, Y](val query: scala.slick.lifted.Query[X, Y, Seq]) {
    def filter(op: Option[_])(f:(X) => Column[Option[Boolean]]) = {
      op map { o => MaybeFilter(query.filter(f)) } getOrElse { this }
    }
  }
```

Regards.

## Corrected example:

```
//Class definition
import scala.slick.driver.H2Driver.simple._
import scala.slick.lifted.{ProvenShape, ForeignKeyQuery}

// A Suppliers table with 6 columns: id, name, street, city, state, zip
class Suppliers(tag: Tag)
  extends Table[(Int, String, String, String, String, String)](tag, "SUPPLIERS") {

  // This is the primary key column:
  def id: Column[Int] = column[Int]("SUP_ID", O.PrimaryKey)
  def name: Column[String] = column[String]("SUP_NAME")
  def street: Column[String] = column[String]("STREET")
  def city: Column[String] = column[String]("CITY")
  def state: Column[String] = column[String]("STATE")
  def zip: Column[String] = column[String]("ZIP")

  // Every table needs a * projection with the same type as the table's type parameter
  def * : ProvenShape[(Int, String, String, String, String, String)] =
    (id, name, street, city, state, zip)
}

//I changed the name of the def from filter to filteredBy to ease the
//implicit conversion 
case class MaybeFilter[X, Y](val query: scala.slick.lifted.Query[X, Y, Seq]) {
  def filteredBy(op: Option[_])(f:(X) => Column[Option[Boolean]]) = {
    op map { o => MaybeFilter(query.filter(f)) } getOrElse { this }
  }
}

//Implicit conversion to the MaybeFilter in order to minimize ceremony
implicit def maybeFilterConversor[X,Y](q:Query[X,Y,Seq]) = new MaybeFilter(q)

val suppliers: TableQuery[Suppliers] = TableQuery[Suppliers]

suppliers += (101, "Acme, Inc.", "99 Market Street", "Groundsville", "CA", "95199")

//Dynamic query here
//try this asigment   val nameFilter:Option[String] = Some("cme")   and see the results
val nameFilter:Option[String] = Some("Acme")
//also try to assign None in here like this   val supIDFilter:Option[Int] = None   and see the results
val supIDFilter:Option[Int] = Some(101)

suppliers
  .filteredBy(supIDFilter){_.id === supIDFilter}
  .filteredBy(nameFilter){_.name like nameFilter.map("%" + _ + "%").getOrElse("")}
  .query.list
```

## Complete example:

https://github.com/neowinx/hello-slick-2.1-dynamic-filter

Comment: The above code fails to compile with Slick 2.1 and Scala 2.11. The "d" parameter in each of the filter clauses is flagged with "missing parameter type" errors. I don't see why this should be the case, because the function parameter "f" in the filter function definition is declared as type X, which should provide the compiler with the necessary type info.  No?  Anyone know how to make the above compile?

Comment: ops.. I copied the original example.. my bad.. I edited my answer in order to include a working example. Also you could check the complete source code at https://github.com/neowinx/hello-slick-2.1-dynamic-filter PS: sorry for the delayed answer.. I've been very busy with college lately... hope It helps you

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the correct migrated code for slick 2.1.0

```
case class MaybeFilter[X, Y](val query: Query[X, Y, Seq]) {
  def filter[T, R: CanBeQueryCondition](data: Option[T])(f: T => X => R) = {
    data.map(v => MaybeFilter(query.withFilter(f(v)))).getOrElse(this) 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are isLocked, isProcessed, etc Options?

Then you can also write things like

```
for (locked <- query.isLocked) { q = q.filter(_.isLocked is locked) }
```

if that's of any consolation :-}

Answer (score -2):

Well, it seems like this code violates OCP. Try to take a look on [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc546578.aspx) - even though it's not on Scala, it explains how to properly design such methods.